# Django with gunicorn and nginx: HTTP 500 not appearing in log files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django app running on a [gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) server with an 
[nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/) up front. 
I need to diagnose a production failure with an [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) outcome,
but the error log files do not contain the information I would expect.
Thusly:

- gunicorn has [setting](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) `errorlog = "/somepath/gunicorn-errors.log"`
- nginx has [setting](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/) `error_log /somepath/nginx-errors.log;`
- My app has an `InternalErrorView` the `dispatch` of which does an
  unconditional `raise Exception("Just for testing.")`
  That view is mapped to URL `/fail_now`
- I have not modified [`handler500`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/)
- When I run my app with `DEBUG=True` and have my browser request 
  `/fail_now`, I see the usual Django error screen alright, including
  the `"Just for testing."` message. Fine.
- When I run my app with `DEBUG=False`, I get a response that consists
  merely of `<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>`, as expected. Fine.
- However, when I look into `gunicorn-errors.log`, there is no entry
  for this HTTP 500 event at all. **Why? How can I get it?** 
  I would like to get a traceback.
- Likewise in `nginx-errors.log`: No trace of a 500 or the `/fail_now` URL.
  **Why?**

*Bonus question:*
When I compare this to my original production problem, I am getting
a different response there: a 9-line document with 
`<h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>` as the central message.
**Why?**

*Bonus question 2:*
When I copy my database contents to my staging server (which is identical
in configuration to the production server) and set
`DEBUG=True` in Django there, `/fail_now` works as expected, but my original
problem still shows up as `<h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>`.
**WTF?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, it took long, but I found it all out:

- The `<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>` response comes from Django's
  `django.views.defaults.server_error` (if no `500.html` template exists).
- The `<h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>` from the bonus question
  comes from gunicorn's `gunicorn.workers.base.handle_error`.
- nginx logs the 500 error in the access log file, not the error log file;
  presumably because it was not nginx itself that failed.
- For `/fail_now`, gunicorn will also log the problem in the access log,
  not the error log; again presumably because gunicorn as such has
  not failed, only the application has.
- My original problem *did* actually appear in the gunicorn error log,
  but I had never searched for it there, because I had
  introduced the log file only freshly (I had relied on Docker `logs`
  output before, which is pretty confusing) and assumed it would be
  better to use the very explicit `InternalErrorView` for initial
  debugging. (This was an idea that was wrong in an interesting way.)
- However, my actual programming error involved sending a response
  with a `Content-Disposition` header (generated in Django code) like this:
  `attachment; filename="dag-wönnegården.pdf"`.
  The special characters are apparently capable of making
  gunicorn stumble when it processes this response.

Writing the question helped me considerably with diagnosing this situation.
Now if this response helps somebody else, 
the StackOverflow magic has worked once again.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lutz! Just for future reference: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1353

Comment: @Lutz Prechelt, I am having a similar issue - trying to get the 'Internal Server Error' page from Gunicorn to redirect instead to my `handler500` setup in Django. If tried everything... Nginx `proxy_intercept_errors off;` declaring custom handler views & urls in Django, etc. etc. Any chance you remember how did you get Gunicorn to bubble up the exception so that I can be managed by Django instead? thanks man, its been hours and hours

Answer (score 1):

may be server response 500 is logged in access_log not in errorlog

in nginx default file

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;
```

i think `<h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>` is generated by nginx in production `

in debug=False

raise exception is treated as error or http500,so unless you changed the view for handler500,default 500 error page will be displayed

debug =true
raise exception is displayed in fancy djnago's debug page